# How to connect to MySQL database from Android?

Tags: android, mysql

I try to connect to MySQL through mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar library.
This is my code:

```
class Test {
    private static final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/db";

    private void getMySQL() {
    Connection con = null;
    String str_res = "";

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        // Properties for user and password. 
        Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user","***");
    p.put("password","***");

        // Now try to connect
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION, p);
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {}    
}
```

But I have a network exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
null
null
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
0
0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It probably means your MySQL listener daemon is not running so there was nothing for the program to connect to.

Comment: Do you have network permission?

Comment: As an aside, this is probably not the best idea. Doing this, means that, first, you need to open up your MySQL server for access from any host for that user (i.e. user@% access) and , second, you would be storing your login credentials in the application. Apps are easily cracked, at which point your database is totally compromised.  You are much better off putting a web service abstraction between your client and the MySQL server, and having the client interact with that web service.

Comment: Yes I have network permission.

Comment: How i can run the MySQL listener?